# test element is visible or not with react testing library

Tags: javascript, testing, frontend, tailwind-css, react-testing-library

I am new to react testing and now I face with a bug.
this is my next.js application component

```
    type NavbarOptionProps = {
  name: string;
  menu?: React.ReactNode;
};

function NavbarOption({ name, menu }: NavbarOptionProps) {
      return (
        <div className="group hover:bg-slate-700/60 relative flex z-20 ">
          <div className="flex items-center justify-center gap-3 w-full h-full px-4 ">
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              icon={faChevronDown}
              style={{ fontSize: 12, color: "#807979", cursor: "pointer" }}
            />
            <span className="  cursor-pointer">{name}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="hidden group-hover:block">{menu}</div>  <--- I set to hide
        </div>
      );
    }
```

I wrote this test:

```
test("displays menu on hover", () => {
  const name = "Example Name";
  const menu = <div>Example Menu</div>;
  render(
    <NavbarOption
      name={name}
      menu={menu}
    />
  );

  const navbarOption = screen.getByText(name);
  expect(screen.queryByText(/Example Menu/i)).not.toBeVisible();

  userEvent.hover(navbarOption);

  const menuElement = screen.getByText(/Example Menu/i);
  expect(menuElement).toBeVisible();
});
```

but I got error like this:

> ● displays menu on hover
>
> ```
> expect(element).not.toBeVisible()
>
> Received element is visible:
>   <div />
> ```

I set my element to be invisible as long as it is not hoverd and set hidden class